# Issue with using xpath to read the xhtml tags

Tags: java, xpath, xhtml

I am using xpath to read the xhtml document, i want to read the all elements inside the `<p>` tag of the xhtml file. For that i am doing something like this.

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();                
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//p[2]/*");                 
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Nodes>>>>>>>>"+nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
}
```

XHMTL sample looks like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>test</title></head>
    <body>
        <p class="default"> <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: sans-serif"> Test Doc</span> </p> 
        <p class="default"> <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: sans-serif"> Test Doc1</span> </p>
        <p class="default"> <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: sans-serif"> Test Doc2</span> </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I am unable to get the nodes inside the `<p>` tag, not not able to enter into the for loop.

Can anybody will help me out in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i  am new to this, can you give detailed answer

Comment: Please add to your question a XHTML sample - complete file including the html tag - that you would expect to work and doesn't.

Comment: If you are using the namespaces, that may be the reason you are not able to access the tag. For that you can refine your xpath expression to be  like ".//*[local-name()='p']". This will return the nodes with out considering a namespace.

Comment: @Alohci, i edited my question by adding sample xhtml file, please have a look

Comment: @Krishnanunni, now i am able to get the node values using the local-name, thanks for your time, If i have multiple paragraphs and i want to access particular paragraph based on the say some id, how can i handle it?

Comment: I have posted an answer. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
       XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(".//*[local-name()='p'][@id='ur_id']");
```

Can you check this? I think this will get you your node. It will be nice to visit http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5/expressions.html and understand the basics of XPath in parsing.

Comment: "//XXX[@attrib='abc']" will select the node with an attribute attrib='abc'

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to print the `nodeValue`s of Element nodes, which is unlikely to be what you want. I expect you want the `nodeValue` of Text nodes.

Another problem may be namespacing. It looks like your xpath is trying to match `p` elements in no namespace, when it should probably be trying to match `p` elements in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [XPathAPI](http://svario.it/xpathapi/) ([javadoc](http://svario.it/xpathapi/doc)) to extract your nodes as a generic Java list.

```
String expr = "//p[2]/*";

Map<String, String> ns = new Map<String, String>;
ns.put("html", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

List<String> nodeValues = XPathAPI.html.selectNodeListAsStrings(doc, expr, ns);
for (String nodeValue : nodesValues) {
    System.out.println("Nodes>>>>>>>> " + nodeValue);
}
```

or

```
List<String> nodeValues = XPathAPI.html.selectListOfNodes(doc, expr, ns);
for (Node node : nodes) {
    System.out.println("Nodes>>>>>>>> " + node.getTextContent());
}
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the XPathAPI library.